# Defining multiple exporters of the same type

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

Is it possible to define the same type of exporter multiple times in OpenTelemetry Collector config?

Given this example:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

exporters:
  prometheus-A:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8889

  prometheus-B:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8890

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics-A:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheus-A]
    metrics-B:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheus-B]
```

I'm getting the following error:

`error decoding 'exporters': unknown type: "prometheus-B" for id: "prometheus-B" (valid values: [prometheusremotewrite file prometheus otlp otlphttp kafka opencensus zipkin debug logging])`

Of course if I change the exporter type to a valid value `prometheus`, there's no way of distinguishing those two exporters:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8889

  prometheus:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8890

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics-A:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheus] # How to distinguish the two?
    metrics-B:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheus] # How to distinguish the two?
```

I'm then getting the following error:

`mapping key "prometheus" already defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receivers, Processors and Exporters accept a list of items.

You need to do it in the following way:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

exporters:
  prometheus/A:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8889

  prometheus/B:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:8890

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheus/A, prometheus/B]
```

Comment: I have provided a list of items in my original example. Why does it work in your case? Could you point to documentation? I couldn't find anything about that but perhaps I wasn't looking in the right place.

Comment: I believe the issue is because of the `-`. That's why the collector is complaining that `unknown type: "prometheus-B"`

Comment: You can just replace `-` with `/` to see if that works out.

Comment: Collector components are identified by `type[/name]`, and that's why this answer works - `prometheus` is a known type, `prometheus-A` is not. That's just the syntax of the opentelemetry collector. It's mentioned in the documentation: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/configuration/#basics